# How to listen for changes with react and firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, api, google-cloud-firestore

I have two separate projects one is a react application and the other one is for my firestore API that I have functions setup. I call these functions in my react application. I have them separated since the firebase package is very large.

I am looking to figure out how to have my data in real time. I know how to setup snapshots in my functions. So I am wondering if I could setup a function that pings my react application(that could be listener for) that something has updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out https://github.com/tylermcginnis/re-base - it allows you to persist your data in the React State mirroring any changes that are made in your database. It was made specifically for Firebase + React.js.

There are endpoints (amongst many others) namely `syncState` which is a two-way bind to state and `bindToState` which is a one-way bind to state.

Hope this helps!